# Test mail not sending in drupal 7 SMTP configuration in windows 2012 server

Tags: smtp, drupal-7, windows-server-2012

I installed and configured SMTP module with proper details in Drupal 7. I tried to send test the mail in Windows 2012 server but am getting the below error.

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. (0)

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
>
> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

The same build is working fine in Windows XP, 07, and Ubuntu environments. What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Correct the TLS port for gmail SMTP configuration. It should be 587. You can refer to below link -

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: I have changed the port number to "587", But still  I am getting the same issue. Find the issue below.

** SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. (0) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists. **

Could you please help on this issue.